# how to use TypeOrm to search for multiple rows containing any one of the mulitiple items in same Column?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

i have a `typeorm + postgresql + node` setup.

My users table has these fields

```
 __________________________
| name | email    | phone |
 __________________________
| n1   | e1@a.com | 1234   |
 __________________________
| n2   | e2@x.com |  2983 |
 __________________________
| n3  |  e3@y.com | 0933 |
 __________________________
```

.....and so on...

if i want to get a row i can use this expression ,

```
Repository.find({
where: { email : 'e2@x.com'},
})
```

But if i want to get all rows which has different email addresses, how can i do that?
ie.  where `email === e2@x.com  || email === e3@z.com || ....`
(the problem is that, we dont know these emails beforehand...the emails can vary... means sometimes we may need to use a group of emails, and some other time, a totally different group of emails etc..it comes from another database select operation)

anyideas on how to do that in TypeOrm?... if a solution is possible with out queryRunner or querybuilder, it will be more easier for a beginner like me..